# Cannot get Specific Content off of Google

Tags: java, android

I am encountering a problem in my Android application where I get all the content on the page, but I only want part of it. Here is part of my code:

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
    String text1 = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();

    if (text1.equals("US Dollar - USD")) {          
        try {

            Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.google.com/finance/market_news?ei=_FLfUbD4JrG90QGf6wE").get();
            String body = doc.body().text();
            textView1.setText(body);

        } catch (IOException e) {


    }
```

Here is what I am getting in my application:

http://oi41.tinypic.com/343kmwx.jpg

The stuff I want in my application starts from "An Ethiopian Airlines........ on 767 Dreamliner fire.

What do I need to do? I am not experienced in CSS, Javascript, or HTML. I have checked all over google too. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting a webpage, so you'll get all the text of a webpage.  You can try to parse out the information you want (this is called screen scraping, and there are libraries for it), but an attempt to do that will be very fragile-  it will break if they change the format of the page at all.  If they provide a real webservice to provide this data you can hit that.  Otherwise what you're trying to do really isn't suggested and will break frequently.  You really shouldn't be doing it.